# How to setup a Yii configuration file - CProfileLogRoute and CWebLogRoute questions

Tags: yii

I'm following the information here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging

Please take a look at my log component on my dev machine configuration file:

```
 'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
                        'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info, profile',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                        'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info, profile',
                        'showInFireBug'=>true,
                    ),
        ),
```

Using CProfileLogRoute is of any use JUST AND ONLY IF we place something like this on our application code:

```
Yii::beginProfile('blockID');
...code block being profiled...
Yii::endProfile('blockID');
```

1)

IF the only purpose is to measure the speed, then what does those **levels**

> 'error, warning, trace, info, private'

really mean on this context ?

Thanks a lot in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like those are remnants from CLogRoute (a parent class) that are unused in the code:
http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/logging/CProfileLogRoute.php

The only variable I tend to set got CProfileLogRoute is 'report':
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CProfileLogRoute#setReport-detail

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I will remove all the others and have only report there as well. Or better yet, don't declared at all. And leave only the class definition.